# Give azure openai an encyclopedia of information

Tags: azure-openai

I am currently dabbling in the Azure OpenAI service. I want to take the default model and knowledge base and now add on to it my own unique information. So, for example, for making a game world, I want to be able to tell it all the main characters, the locations, the major factions, and the relationships between all these entities.

Now I know that I can fine-tune my model, providing hundreds of prompt-answer pairs, and I suppose I could fill that out by saying things like:

Who are all the members of the Borean Clan? King Jappy, Queen Stefanos, Sir Barmyn, etc.

Is that really the only way, though? And won't this still create the possibility that the AI will generate text responses that are outside of this encyclopedia of knowledge, referencing people and places that don't actually exist in the game world?

I guess I'm just wondering if there's a better way to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested approach from Microsoft is not to fine-tune the model in your case. There are several options:

- at the moment, you can have a look to this demo which is based on a Cognitive Search index to provide details: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo
- in a few days, you should also see the arrival of the preview feature of "Add your data" feature in Azure OpenAI Studio, which has been announced at Build event a few days ago: see video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SNfeVop4zM). This accelerates the ability to query your own data while using Azure OpenAI

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess this highlights how AI services are a bleeding-edge technology, and basic functionality is still being actively developed. Can't wait to find out more about the "Add your data" feature for Azure OpenAI.

Comment: Come back in less than 2 weeks to check ;)